# Java lambda-expressions: Combinator-Pattern Improvement

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I found this article online: https://gtrefs.github.io/code/combinator-pattern/ . The author describes a validation process for users on a website that asks for a name, an E-Mail and the age. It will output an error message if the validation process fails.

In my opinion, this approach is very nice to keep the code understandable. However, his solution has a disadvantage. In the end, this pattern produced only one error at the time. When the name is empty and the e-mail does not contain an @-sign it prints "The name is empty" only.

Based on the code snippet

```
static UserValidtion all(UserValidation... validations){ 
  // Your code here 
}
```

in the end of the article I tried to create a method that produces a list of these errors.

But I came up with a very poor solution that prints the reasons inside interface UserValidation. Altough, it produces a NullPointerException (here you can execute my code: http://tpcg.io/WSI2u3):

UserValidation.java

```
static UserValidation all(UserValidation... validations){
        return user -> 
        {
            Arrays.stream(validations).forEach(validation -> {
                //returns the reason  why one of the user inputs is not valid
                System.out.println(validation.apply(user).getReason()); 
                //I don't know how to combine the reasons here to have a proper output in the main. 
            });

            return null;
        };
    }
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserValidation rules[] = {UserValidation.nameIsNotEmpty(),UserValidation.eMailContainsAtSign()};
        UserValidation validation = UserValidation.all(rules);
        User gregor = new User("", 30, "mailmailinator.com");
        ValidationResult result = validation.apply(gregor);     
        result.getReason().ifPresent(System.out::println); 

    }
}
```

I am pretty unexpirienced with the lambda expressions but I tried a lot and it did not fit into this approach.
This is what I tried:

- Added an static ArrayList to the interface UserValidation to save the passed reasons. Did not work because the call in the main-method accepts a UserValidation-Object only.
- added an ArrayList to the interface ValidationResult to store a list of reasons. Did not work either because I was not able to access all reasons at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create a `CompositeValidationResult` that takes a number of `ValidationResult` and gives you a `List<String>` rather than an `Optional<String>`. Then your `all` would simply `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

I did couple of changes in your code

```
    static Function< User, List<ValidationResult> > all(UserValidation... validations){
    return user -> 
    {
        return Arrays.stream(validations).map(validation -> 
            validation.apply(user)
        ).filter(vr-> !vr.isValid())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    };
}
```

and changed the main to display validation error.

```
        UserValidation rules[] = {UserValidation.nameIsNotEmpty(),UserValidation.eMailContainsAtSign()};
    Function< User, List<ValidationResult> > validation = UserValidation.all(rules);
    User gregor = new User("", 30, "mailmailinator.com");
    List<ValidationResult> result = validation.apply(gregor);

    result.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getReason().get()));
```

Looks like it will work as you have asked.